# Can I restructure existing MVC 5 project into Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a project which started simple and it is now growing.  I started it a ASP NET MVC 5 and did not consider Areas as a way to organize back then.

I now need to implement a new feature in the same project.

Question:
given that my project is essentially organized as one Controller / Model / View folder(s).  Is it possible to restructure into Areas so that I put the existing feature in one Area, and the new requirement feature into a new separate Area.  I have not used Area in the past but from what I read so far, it simple to implement in new project. My concern is breaking the existing app.

I would appreciate any advise, example or a reference link .

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use separate ares.But as now you are in the mid of the project it will be lil bit difficult.However if need you can do it carefully since you breaking your existing project.

Its better to refer the following link before do it...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/714356/Areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 1):

Mid project i decided to split project into 3 areas, 1 for admin, 2 for 2 different types of users.
I realizes that area is very much like completely new application with other application.
In the end i abandoned areas completely having no real benefit.
While areas might be useful to someone, i finished my project without em, and not planning to use areas again.